# Is there code I can use to hide all rows except for the row containing the value I am searching?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a search box that auto opens when the file is started requesting the target value. I have tried many times to write something that will hide all rows above and below the value once found, with no avail.

```
Private Sub Summary_Click()
Dim EMPLID As String

EMPLID = Application.InputBox("Enter Your Employee Number", "Employee Number")

With Sheets("Tracking Data").Range("E:E")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=EMPLID, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
Unload Me

End Sub
```

I would like to search for EMPLID 12345, return only that row (including the header on Row 1, with all other rows hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just *plain* use of `Autofilter()`:

```
Private Sub Summary_Click()
    Dim EMPLID As String

    EMPLID = Application.InputBox("Enter Your Employee Number", "Employee Number")

    With Sheets("Tracking Data").Range("E:E")
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=EMPLID
        If WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) = 1 Then ' if only header row filtered -> no match found
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
            .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove AutoFilter and show all data
        End If
    End With
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

BTW I'd suggest you some little enhancements:

1. limit the searching range to the actual data extensions, instead of the whole column (some 1 million row)
2. Don't use `Unload Me` inside a UserForm code. Adopt `Hide.Me` and move `Unload Me` to the `Userform` calling sub (the one where you place some `With New MyUserform` statement or the likes)

like follows:

```
Private Sub Summary_Click()
    Dim EMPLID As String

    EMPLID = Application.InputBox("Enter Your Employee Number", "Employee Number")

    With Sheets("Tracking Data")
        With .Range("E1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=EMPLID
            If WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) = 1 Then ' if only header row filtered -> no match found
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
                .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove AutoFilter and show all data
            End If
        End With
    End With
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an autofilter.

```
Private Sub Summary_Click()
Dim EMPLID As String

EMPLID = Application.InputBox("Enter Your Employee Number", "Employee Number")

With Sheets("Tracking Data").Range("E:E")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=EMPLID, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            .autofilter
            .autofilter field:=1, criteria1:=EMPLID 
            Application.Goto Rng, True
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
    End With
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the autofilter answer just posted.  But a more-literal answer that actually hides the rows, except row 1 and the one where 'Rng' is, goes like this:

```
Sub tst()
    Dim rng As Range, bottom As Range
    Set rng = [D3]  ' Just example data
    rng.Activate   ' put cursor on rng  
    ' Assumes Column A has data, otherwise use column with Rng in it
    Set bottom = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)  ' finds last row in A with any data in it      
    If rng.Row > 2 Then Range(Rows(2), Rows(rng.Row - 1)).Hidden = True ' Hide all rows above RNG      
    If rng.Row < bottom.Row Then Range(Rows(rng.Row + 1), Rows(bottom.Row)).Hidden = True  ' Hide rows below  
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to accomplish your task.

```
Private Sub Summary_Click()
Dim EMPLID As String, cl As Range

EMPLID = Application.InputBox("Enter Your Employee Number", "Employee Number")

    With Sheets("Tracking Data")
        For Each cl In .Range("E2", .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Not cl.Value = EMPLID Then
                cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next cl
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub test()
    Dim EMPLID As String
    Dim rngDB As Range, Rng As Range, rngU As Range
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim strAddress As String

    EMPLID = Application.InputBox("Enter Your Employee Number", "Employee Number")


    Set Ws = Sheets("Tracking Data")
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("e1", .Range("e" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    With rngDB
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=EMPLID, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            strAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                If rngU Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngU = Rng

                Else
                    Set rngU = Union(rngU, Rng)
                End If
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Rng.Address <> strAddress

        End If
    End With
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    Else
        rngDB.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        rngU.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

## Find vs Parent

To not cramp your style, I've only removed the arguments **SearchDirection** and **MatchCase** because they were using default parameters and I've added the '**Parent**' part which is referring to the worksheet (Tracking Data).

```
Private Sub Summary_Click()

Dim EMPLID As String

EMPLID = Application.InputBox("Enter Your Employee Number", "Employee Number")

With Sheets("Tracking Data").Range("E:E")
        Set rng = .Find(What:=EMPLID, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            With .Parent
                .Cells(2, 1).Resize(rng.Row - 2).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Cells(rng.Row + 1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - rng.Row) _
                        .EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End With
            Application.Goto Rng, True         
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing found"
        End If
End With
Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Find carries parameters over from both previous uses in VBA and from the normal user-accessible version. Specifying all parameters every time is a good idea.